# How to specify number of columns allowed in grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I would like to get the grid working in such way that it can have 1 or even number of columns depending on total width. All columns should wrapped to one on minimum width and then 2, 4 columns as a width increase.
I want to avoid situation when on some width there are three columns and two rows and the second row does have only one last element. It does not look so nice.

```
<div class="info">
    <div><i class="material-icons">location_on</i>Address</div>
    <div><i class="material-icons">call</i>Phone</div>
    <div><i class="material-icons">email</i>Email</div>
    <div><i class="material-icons">public</i>Web</div>
</div>
```

```
.info {
    display: grid;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 400px);
    grid-gap: 0px 0px;
}
```

Comment: No this is not possible without specifying the number of columns

Comment: As I understood I need to add media query for each I want. So it will be 4 columns at width X, 2 columns at width Y and one column at width Z right?